# is there a way to change the icons of the stepper form in Vuetify-jsonschema-form Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a form wizard, and would like to over ride the default icons / steps in the stepper, I don't seem to be able to find an option but I might be missing something. Is there anyway to customize the Icons for each step?

[button that I'm trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e2Iy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without some "tricks", you can change 3 icons
Complete, Edit and Error. [Check them here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper-step/#api-props)

If you need something more you'll probably need more work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, any idea how to do even that in VJSF library ? I have tried to use x-prop but doesn't seem to affect the stepper [link]https://koumoul-dev.github.io/vuetify-jsonschema-form/latest/examples#default-values

Also seems like there is a way of extending a component, but again for Vuetify itself and not for VJSF [link]https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7049 , I'm trying to avoid building forms in html and stick to Schema somehow.

Comment: Unless it is something that you really need, or you trust, i do not advise using modules with less than 1000 stars on github

Comment: thanks, I need something good to generate forms schemas and verify it, it's been hard to find any library that has all of that